# makefile: code is not recompiled when macros change

Tags: c, makefile

I have two makefiles: `a.mk` and `b.mk`. For context, I have a project that shares some application-level code, but also has some independent platform specific code. The two makefiles compile for different platforms. Each makefile compiles some subset of my C project with a set of macros. For example, given the folder containing `foo.c bar.c baz.c qux.c`, makefile `a.mk` might compile `foo.c baz.c qux.c` with macro `-DHAS_FOO=1` and makefile `b.mk` might compile `bar.c baz.c qux.c` with macro `-DHAS_FOO=0`. The source files have some code blocks that do things based on the defines:

```c
#if HAS_FOO
// call some function defined in foo.c
#endif
```

I'm noticing when building with `b.mk` after `a.mk`, the shared dependencies `baz.c` and `qux.c` are not recompiled, despite the differing set of macros causing changes in the code, leading to undefined reference errors. What can I do to resolve this? I often want to build for both platforms, and having to `clean` before running each target is not ideal.

Let me know if I need to provide more concrete information.

Comment: Make only looks at the files. It has no knowledge of code dependencies. The easiest solution would be to build in different directories, so you have two sets of object files.

Comment: Great idea Emanuel. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Emanuel commented, "make" just takes files into account, exactly their modification time. It does not know any dependency on different defines. Think of the Makefile as a rule set creating a static dependency tree. Each file can have only one instance in there.

The most straight-forward way is to build for each target separately. You can accomplish this with separated build directories or different filenames of the object files.